# Error establishing a database connection wordpress inspite of correct credentials in config file

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm getting Error establishing a database connection error whenever I load my HomePage i.e index.php.

I have created a new **test.php** file with the same credentials as **wp-config.php** file to check the credentials and it works fine. I get 
Connected successfully message.

But when I run **index.php** file I get

> Error establishing a database connection.

What could cause this error?

**Test.php** file

```
    <?php

    $link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'dbname');

    if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    echo 'Connected successfully';

    mysql_close($link);

    ?>
```

Comment: the exact error message is?

Comment: what you have in `index.php`? where its located? how do you call it( request url )?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with one of my plugins. I had to remove the plugin to make it work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all above connection code from test.php file.
just use **global $wpdb;** in beginning of file & it will give you connectivity from the config file. its wordpress's default functionality.